# Is there a way to convert a string into a float without losing accuracy?

Tags: c++, json, floating-point, representation

I have float values with high precision. When I convert them to a string I lose precision.

I am storing this float value in a Json::Value object. And I need to later take the float back out of the Json::Value object without losing precision.

I am using this float value to predict values. When the float loses precision the prediction is weaker. Before I put it into this Json object it is making more accurate calculations.

Here is the code:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <jsoncpp/json/json.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    float num = 0.0874833928293906f;
    
    Json::Value weight(num);
    
    cout << "Original float value: " << num << endl;
    cout << "Original float value being stored in Json::Value: " << weight.asString() << endl;

    num = weight.asFloat();

    cout << "Float once being converted back to float from string: " << num << endl; 
}
```

Output:

```
Original float value: 0.0874834
Original float value being stored in Json::Value: 0.087483391165733337
Float once being converted back to float from string: 0.0874834
```

As you can see the float value retains its precision upon input to json and is being stored as a json double. When I convert the float to a string it loses precision. When I convert the Json::Value object to a float it loses precision.

Because the output of the calculation changed I know that the float is being represented differently before and after.

Is there any way I can keep the precision that the float had before after holding it in a Json::Value object?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. When I assign these literal constants (adding an 'f' suffix, e.g. `-0.85028403997421265f`) to `float` variables, then print them with `printf` format `%.20f`, I get back string representations that match the input. In general, use of the `f` suffix is needed to prevent potential double-rounding effects.

Comment: When you say "convert them back to float", are you converting them to `float` or to `double`?

Comment: @Eljay In c++ I store them in float variables. The precision got to be high during back propagation. C++ could do calculations with those high precision numbers that were stored in floats. Meaning that it seems to be able to represent them. When I try to convert Json::Value to float it takes away the precision I initially had. My neural network performs 9% worse. I 100% mean float.

Comment: Even though the `float` input data is given to 16 decimal digits here, the `float` data type only provides accuracy equivalent to 6 to 7 decimal digits. You may want to provide actual code that others can use to reproduce the problem. This *could* just be an issue of textual representation.

Comment: I can put it on github I guess

Comment: @njuffa what is textual representation?

Comment: Since JSON uses `double`, why don't you try to use `double` for the C++ as well?

Comment: @Eljay double slow can't use double sorry

Comment: @Nick "textual representation" is the representation of a collection of bits as text. For example, the 32 bits with a value of `0xbf59ac37`, interpreted as a `float` based on IEEE-754 `binary32` format can be represented in text as `-0.85028403997421265f`, or `-0.85028404f`. Either of these two textual representations represent the same IEEE-754 `binary32` (single precision) encoding.

Comment: @njuffa What's strange is that the error increases on my network if those numbers represent the same thing. Do you think that's strange?

Comment: @Nick If you were to post a minimal self-contained example code *directly in the question* it would allow others to reproduce the problem and suggest fixes. Right now it is not possible to tell whether there is an actual problem with the data, or whether it is a matter of confusion caused by different textual representations.

Comment: @njuffa I will add my network code. This is 300 lines or so is this too big?

Comment: @Nick Demonstrating a straightforward problem with numeric conversion should not require 300 lines of code. Nobody wants to dig through that much code. Minimal means just that: the smallest program possible that still reproduces the issue. IMHO that should be doable in 30 lines of code at most.

Comment: @njuffa oh i see

Comment: @Nick *When I try to convert Json::Value to float it takes away the precision I initially had.* -- If it's that function, then you should focus on that, not what the calculations do or what you are calculating.

Comment: @Nick *double slow can't use double sorry* -- Are you running an optimized, release build, or a non-optimized build?  What compiler are you using?  What compiler options did you use (again, are you building your program with optimizations)?  Anytime there is an issue with the speed of a C++ program, it is required that you state, compiler, compiler version, and build options.  If you are running an unoptimized build, then the timings that you are seeing between float and double are meaningless.  Only an optimized build will determine if truly doubles are "slow".

Comment: @njuffa I fixed the question. Now I present a scenario that is like the one from the network

Comment: @Nick: In your example, when you print `num` prior to JSON in the beginning and after JSON at the end, use the same precision as is used for the input, e.g. `std::setprecision(18)`. Update the question with the output after that change.

Comment: Nick, code is simply printing with reduced precession.  Alter printing to output more precision.

Comment: `0.0874833928293906` is not exactly presentable as a `float` (assuming IEEE-754 `binary32` format). One textual representation of the `float` encodings available in its vicinity is `0.08748338371515274, 0.087483391165733337, 0.087483398616313934`. Of these, the middle one is the closest to the desired value.

Comment: Nick, "Because the output of the calculation changed I know that the float is being represented differently before and after." this is incorrect.  Unless `num` prints  significantly differently or different with the _same_ number of decimal places, we do _not_ know the `num` has changed.  All you have demo'd is a change in output precision of potentially the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updated answer:

as @njuffa mentioned, your demo code maybe issue of textual representation, i write code to test it as below

```
    float num = 0.0874833928293906f;//maybe this is the precision lost place, it's not about jsoncpp
    
    Json::Value weight(num);
    float back_num = weight.asFloat();

    if (memcmp(&num, &back_num, sizeof(num)) == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "num and back_num is identical" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "num and back_num is not identical" << std::endl;
    }
```

and the output is:

num and back_num **is** identical

I even tried json serilize and deserilize, the result is still identical.

So I think maybe the precision lost problem is not caused by jsoncpp, you should dig a little more to find the real issue.

original answer:

how about use int instead of float during transport (like multiply by 10000000000), and convert back to float in you business code.

Comment: I tried this. this is a very good idea. For me it did not work. This is the code I used.            `this->layers[i].neurons[j].weights[z].setWeight(((float)(itr->asDouble()*100000000))*pow(10,-8));`

Comment: @Nick -- You are calling `pow(10,-8)` when you could have simply saved time by providing the constant `0.00000001`.  Calling a floating point function like `pow` over and over again with the same constant values is a waste of time.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am not very smart paul

Comment: Tony_Tong, scaling by a non-power-of-2 like 10000000000 or `pow(10,-8)` introduces error - about 1/2 of the least significant bit

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica  sorry, I don't understand your replay very well,  you mean scaling float to int may still lost precision?

Comment: @Tony_Tong Given `num`, (the FP value closest to 0.0874833928293906f), multiplying  `num`  by 10000000000 results in a product that is not exactly  `num` * 10000000000, but a rounded product, thus moving away from OP's goal of "without losing accuracy".  `num` multiplied by 256 ( a power of 2) is possible to do exactly.

Comment: @Tony_Tong yes you see, I did not know that you could view the float number's representation. I am new to cs and I'm glad that I asked this question. Because I learned something new. The answer seems to be that when converting from float to string and back to float, when the float appears to lose accuracy it is still being represented the same. I did find the bug I forgot to add biases LOL. so you are right that it is not the real issue. Thank you

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Oh, I See, you're right,  multiplied by a power of 2 is better

Comment: @Nick You're welcome,  I also leaned something new, :)